# reset recoil state to default not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, recoiljs

tried to reset recoil state to its default value using `useResetRecoilState`but not working
This is my code

```
import {filter} from '..appl/recoil/atoms';
import { useResetRecoilState } from 'recoil';
let filterReset = () => { useResetRecoilState(filter); }
.
.
onSignOut = () => { 
/*Code for signout and other stuff*/
filterReset();
 }
```

recoil state code is :

```
import { atom, useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
export const filter = atom({
  key: 'filter',
  default: {
    handlers: [],
    product: '',
    origin: '',
    destination: ''
}
}
```

used this [documentation](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useResetRecoilState/) but didn't help

Answer (score 2):

useResetRecoilState returns a function that resets the recoil state. It should be used like this:

```
import {filter} from '..appl/recoil/atoms';
import { useResetRecoilState } from 'recoil';

onSignOut = () => { 
    const filterReset = useResetRecoilState(filter);
    /*Code for signout and other stuff*/
    filterReset();
}
```

Comment: tried it .....but no effect